# Error building Matlab table from variable values in a different table

Tags: matlab

Trying to build a table in Matlab to build a simple 3 by x table.

I have a larger table that has a series of serial numbers for example:

[image]

I am trying to store those same numbers in the first column of my new table `Compensation_Table` under the variable name `Serial_Number`. See my below script as an example of what I am doing.

```
SN = 0;
WT = 0;
CM = 0;

SerialNumber = {};
WearTime = {};
Commands = {};

Compensation_Table = table(SerialNumber, WearTime, Commands);
Compensation_Table.Properties.VariableNames = {'Serial_Number', 'Wear_Time', 'Commands'};

for SN_ind = 1:height(Data_Analysis_Table)
    SN = cell2mat(Data_Analysis_Table.Serial_Number(SN_ind));
    
    Compensation_Table.SerialNumber(SN_ind) = SN;
    Compensation_Table.WearTime(SN_ind) = WT;
    Compensation_Table.Commands(SN_ind) = CM;
end
```

However when I do so I am presented with this error.

`Unable to perform assignment because the indices on the left side are not compatible with the size of the right side.`

Not sure why this is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that your serial number column is populated with `1x1` cell-arrays which you are trying to append a 1xn char-array to. Here is a simple demonstration

```
a = {'row 1 string';'row 2 another string'} % a simple cell array of strings
b = cell2table(a)
b{end+1,1} = 'asdfasdf' % or b.a{end+1} = 'asdfasdf';
```

Here the last line will issue the error

> The number of table variables in an assignment must match.

However the following will work because the right-hand side is a `1x1` cell-array:

```
b{end+1,1} = {'asdfasdf'}; % or b.a{end+1} = {'asdfasdf'};
b{end+1,1}={[1 2 3;4 5 6]}; %
```

There are two possible fixes: 1. convert char-array strings to newer style string-variables (see [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html)), or 2. store the values as `1x1` cell arrays.

The first solution is to convert all your char-arrays to strings with `string` before your look; to do this try the following

```
Data_Analysis_Table.Serial_Number=string(Data_Analysis_Table.Serial_Number);
```

However, you would then need to proceed by making sure that all traditional char-arrays and string-cells are converted to the newer string data type (see [string docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html) for more information).

An alternate way to proceed with char-arrays and cell-strings is to store the serial number as a cell in the new table by either

1. remove the `cell2mat` conversion to char-array in the first line of your loop
2. replace `SN` with `{SN}` (ie. surround `SN` with braces `{}`)  by changing the second line in your loop to read one of the following

   - `compensation_table.SerialNumber(SN_ind) = {SN};`
   - `compensation_table.SerialNumber{SN_ind} =  SN ;`

   Notice the different uses of braces to create a cell array or store data inside of an element of a cell-array.